# platform exception on YouTube_player_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-api, youtube-player-flutter

I implemented a YouTube player flutter package, but it keeps returning platform exception with circularprogressindicator on the frame, while trying to play the video.

here is the error
VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, A UIKitView widget is trying to create a PlatformView with an unregistered type: < com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview >, If you are the author of the PlatformView, make sure `registerViewFactory` is invoked.
See: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views#on-the-platform-side-1 for more details.
If you are not the author of the PlatformView, make sure to call `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register`., null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)

#2      PlatformViewsService.initUiKitView (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:242:5)

#3      _UiKitViewState._createNewUiKitView (package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:649:44)
<asynchronous suspensi<…>

searched online some said adding the following io.flutter.embedded_views_preview NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to info.plist worked but I tried it, didn't work. side note, I am testing on iPhone simulator

Answer (score 0):

The package **Youtube Player Flutter** is only supported for android and ios as of Aug, 2023
https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter

You should be using **Youtube Player IFrame** if you want to work with web as well
https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe

Comment: the intention is to use it for android and iOS but I can't simulate on my iOS simulator, does it mean it will work on an actual iOS device ?